Unable to Retrieve Drive Items After Successful Microsoft Drive Authentication
I'm working on a web application and trying to integrate Microsoft Drive using Node.js and Passport. This is my first time working with Microsoft integration. I've set up the authentication process with the following code:
const MicrosoftStrategy = require('passport-microsoft').Strategy;

passport.use(
    new MicrosoftStrategy(
        {
            authorizationURL: `${process.env.MICROSOFT_URL}/authorize`,
            callbackURL: `${process.env.CALLBACK_URL}/oauth/microsoft/callback`,
            clientID: process.env.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET,
            tokenURL: `${process.env.MICROSOFT_URL}/token`
        },
        (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
            profile.tokens = { microsoft: { accessToken, refreshToken } };
            cb(null, profile);
        }
    )
);

router.get(
    '/auth/microsoft',
    passport.authenticate('microsoft', { scope: ['user.read', 'offline_access', 'Files.Read.All', 'Files.Read', 'Files.ReadWrite.All', 'Sites.Read.All', 'Sites.ReadWrite.All', 'consent'] })
);

The authentication is successful, and I receive both the accessToken and refreshToken. However, when I attempt to list the files in the root directory using this cURL command:
curl -X GET \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children"

I get the following response:
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)","value":[]}

I can see that there are several folders and one file in the root directory(please chekc the attached screenshot.), but none of these items are being listed.
Can anyone help me figure out what might be going wrong?
I am expecting list of folder and files.

Hi, have you tried the same API call in Graph Explorer ?

Also, please see if you can see with this API call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root?$expand=children($select=id,name)

The above call will show you a children property in the json that it outputs.

Thank you for your time. Yes, it works in Graph Explorer. When I checked, it had a different access token there. If I use the same access token in the curl command, it works. So, I am having doubts about my permissions. Can you please check the code and confirm if it needs any other permissions or scopes? Do I need to grant any permissions to the app I created? Thank you once again.

Great!, what kind of app are you creating? A delegated or daemon app? Which account are you using to login? Is it Microsoft account or work/school account?

A delegated app. I am using a Gmail account like abcd@gmail.com.

My aim is to integrate OneDrive with my web app. This will allow users to sync their data from the app to OneDrive with a single click.
